# Redirect single webpage into other page in same path with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to 301 redirect a webpage "somepage.php" to "abc_somepage.php" (so the new name contains the old name  - i don't know whether that is important) **in the same path of the request URL**. The new page should get possible parameters passed.

I can easily do a `RewriteRule` or a `Redirect 301` with a hardcoded full path as destination, but I fail to find a general rule which redirects all requests of somepage.php to abc_somepage.php in the some path without explicitly stating the destination path. Can you tell me how to do that?

**Edit:**
Maybe there are some points I need to add:

1.) I only want to redirect "somepage.php" but not "someotherpage.php"

2.) There will be a further redirect which will effect the request, but I thought when I do the redirect above as the first redirect than the following redirects will behave same way as if the user called "abc_somepage.php" directly ?!

This redirect is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ main.php?path=hello/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Are you sure you [need mod_rewrite to do this](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite)? I notice the first answer is already steering you away from it.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Unfortunally I did not understand "These examples assume the RewriteRules are not placed in a directory context (i.e., not in a .htaccess file nor in a <Directory> section)." in the linked source. What I understood is that it is recommended to use other orders than "RewriteRule" in certain cases - but that would still leave the problem how I could state sourcepath and destination path relatively ?!  I am sorry if I understood something wrong in this comment but I am not an expert :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch ^/((?!abc_).+?).php$ /abc_$1.p
```

Comment: I saw you edited your post, but unfortunally "RedirectMatch ^/((?!abc_).+?).php$ /abc_$1.p" does not seem to work and redirects to: "HTTP_HOST/abc_subfolder/somepage.p?path=hello/somepage.php" in my test. I edited my question above, because maybe I did not give all details properly but I tried to keep my question simple. But also when I remove the second redirect (stated in my point 2) I get "HTTP_HOST/abc_subfolder/somepage.p"

Comment: @Wooz sorry, but I dont understand the edited part of your question. Its preety unclear what your goal is.

Comment: I am sorry, actually the edits probably are not very helpful. I just added the second point in case it does have an impact which I myself can't see. So it is likely that it is not needed at all. The first point is because that your solutions both seemed to redirect ALL pages to "abc_" but I really just want "somepage.php" to be redirected (but that at any path it occurs). This surely could easily be healed with the source condition. The problem is the target path which lead to the wrong destination "HTTP_HOST/abc_subfolder/somepage.p" in the above answer when I tested it.